# How to remove a ceiling light when nut turns but doesn't unscrew and globe doesnt turn?

Tags: light-fixture

Help! I'm trying to replace light bulbs in a ceiling light. The nut turns but it doesn't unscrew. I tried WD-40 but it didn't help. I can't turn the glass globe due to the awkward shape of the light fixture. [image: Image of ceiling light with globe]

Comment: When you turn the  nut does it create a little bit of slack, meaning does the Glass start to get a little looser.  The nut is attached to a threaded rod and that threaded rod is also threaded into a bracket up inside the electrical box so it’s possible if you keep turning it all on thread it from the bracket.  Sometimes pulling down on the nut while you turn it will help to move things.

Comment: Don't ever use WD-40 on random things, especially not things which *are in fact* already turning.  WD-40 is not a magic fixer-all. Actually it's an Atlas missile polish - seriously, look it up.  It just has a fantastic marketing department, who says it is good at many things (it is poor at many things). It is, however, great at degrading many materials - it just takes months for the damage to appear. What you actually want is Kroil or Liquid Wrench - those actually *are* penetrating oils, but every bit as corrosive.

Answer (score 1):

Pull down hard and then turn the nut (perhaps use locking pliers)

what has probably happened is that a different nut at the top has loosened and is spinning freely along with the shaft, while the bottom nut has frozen up.

pulling down will increase friction with the nut and hopefully allow it to unscrew.

Answer (score 1):

If the space above the ceiling is accessible (is there an attic space above?) you might be able to go up and see why the screw is spinning.

In a worst-case scenario, if you can get a hacksaw between the nut and the globe you could saw through the screw. You'd then have to either replace the screw or add an extension (assuming one of these is possible) so you can resecure the globe after replacing the lights.